# Android-NDK Linker, ld 2.23.2 failed to open object files specified in linker script

Tags: c++, linker, android-ndk

I was cross-compiling some libraries on Windows 7, using Android NDK.

The linker failed while trying to create shared library for ARM. The problem is that, the libtool generated linker script like the following:

```
input ( 
subsys/.lib/file1.o
subsys/.lib/file2.o
…
)
```

and I had the -L pointing to the right directory, like

```
-Lc:/build/tree/path.../component
```

where component contains subsys directory.

With -verbose passed to ld, I'd seen message like:

```
*toolchain-path/*ld.exe Attempted to open c:/build/tree/path.../component/subsys/.lib/file.o failed
```

and repeat the attempt to open sub sys/.lib/file.o on every library path listed with -L options.

Does anyone know what's wrong with the linker?

Comment: Does the file `c:/build/tree/path.../component/subsys/.lib/file.o` exist?

Comment: Windows used to have a limit on file length; some 3rd party tools may still use it. The remedy used to be placing the files closer to the root directory. Also, many tools have problems with spaces in paths.